# listed companies with significant bitcoin revenue

Tags: business

The currency flowing through listed companies on the main stock exchanges of the world is mainly of the standard, fiat kind.

Does anyone know if there are any listed companies out there on any major stock exchange for which a significant proportion of turnover, say more than 5% is in bitcoin or other cryptocurrency?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [publicly listed bitcoin mining companies](https://www.barrons.com/articles/bitcoin-mining-stocks-crypto-51637337835). I believe that Marathon Digital does hodl bitcoin (and they even raised money to PURCHASE bitcoin some weeks ago). You could also take a look at Coinbase and other exchanges but as far as I know they don't keep the transactions fees they take in bitcoin but trade them to this Dollar-Shitcoin.

Besides these options the only way to find such companies is to find companies that allow bitcoin payments and a significant amount of their users prefers this option. But the companies I know that do that are pretty small and not public...